# SQL AZURE: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am running the following Create Table.

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TBL_PRIMES] 
(
  [MY_VALUE] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [MY_DIVISION] [bigint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [CHK_TBL_PRIMES] CHECK ([MY_DIVISION] - 0),
  [MY_TIME] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TBL_PRIMES] DEFAULT (GETDATE())
  CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_PRIMES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MY_VALUE] ASC)
) ON PS_HASH_BY_VALUE ([MY_VALUE])
GO
```

Can someone please help me to understand the error and give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `CHECK` constraint like this:

```
 [MY_DIVISION] [bigint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [CHK_TBL_PRIMES] CHECK ([MY_DIVISION] - 0),
```

That is not a boolean expression; it is an arithmetic expression.  If I had to guess, you intend:

```
 [MY_DIVISION] [bigint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [CHK_TBL_PRIMES] CHECK ([MY_DIVISION] > 0),
```